# Component vuejs2 setting default value and then passing that back to the parent

Tags: vue.js, components, default-value, v-select

Update: I have some vue code, main.vue which I would like to call a component, which does three things:

1. Allows the user to pass to the component a set of items, one of which can be selected in the component pulldown, using the v-select and v-model API.
2. Pass to the component the default pulldown item
3. Then communicate back to the parent the selected option from the component's pull-down.

So for example, I can call the component in the main.vue (parent):

```
<componentPullDown :items="customers", :defaultSelected="preferredCustomer"/>
```

Then within the componentPullDown vue component, I have the

```
      <div class="box">
      <span class="box-header">Speciality</span>
      <v-select
        label="customer"
        :options="items"
        :clearable="false"
        :item-text="preferredCustomer"           
        v-model="selectedCustomer"
        return-object
      />
      <span class="box-label">
      </span>
    </div>
```

I have the options for the list working fine, but I can't get the default value to work, or communicate back to the parent the option selected when the pulldown item has changed.

Thanks.
Any help would be great.

Comment: I think if you put more codes in the question, others better could help you. For example the process that could be done in the component is unclear. Suppose that you want to answer your own question, does these codes enough?

Comment: I confirm we're a bit helpless here without more details. What do you need to achieve? What have you tried? What's the error if you have one?

Comment: Hi. I'm wanting to create a component which has a v-select pull down box which can be instantiated from parent say menu.vue, the component is say banner.vue. I'd like to pass the list of values to the banner.vue, which is then displayed in the v-select model and then the option selected is passed back up to the menu. Thank you.